# Create Campaigns, set bids and buy adds from DoubleClick Bid Manager API

Tags: google-api-python-client, double-click-advertising

Is it possible with the Google DoubleClick Bid Manager API to create campaigns, set bids and buy adds?, I have checked the documentation and it seems that there are limited endpoints.

These are all the available endpoints according to the documentation:

- doubleclickbidmanager.lineitems.downloadlineitems    Retrieves line items in CSV format.
- doubleclickbidmanager.lineitems.uploadlineitems  Uploads line items in
  CSV format.
- doubleclickbidmanager.queries.createquery    Creates a query.
- doubleclickbidmanager.queries.deletequery    Deletes a stored query as
  well as the associated stored reports.
- doubleclickbidmanager.queries.getquery   Retrieves a stored query.
- doubleclickbidmanager.queries.listqueries    Retrieves stored queries.
- doubleclickbidmanager.queries.runquery   Runs a stored query to
  generate a report.
- doubleclickbidmanager.reports.listreports    Retrieves stored reports.
- doubleclickbidmanager.sdf.download   Retrieves entities in SDF format.

None of these endpoints can do tasks as buy ads, set bids or create campaigns, so I think those tasks can only be done through the UI and not with the API.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I would be very interested in that too but to the best of my knowledge, those are all what DBM can provide us at the moment. As this API is v1, I think we can expect more endpoints in the near future. [Getting Started with DBM API](https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/guides/getting-started-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to solve this problem. The actual API v1 has this capabilities but the documentation is not very clear about it.

You need to download your Line Items file as CSV or any other supported format, then from that downloaded file you must edit it with any script you want, so you must edit the columns of Status to perform this operation. Also, if you want to create a new campaign, you will need to do the same for new Line Items. After editing the CSV or created one, you must uploaded back to google with the relative endpoint: uploadlineitems.

Google will answer to the owner of the Bid Manager account what changes were accepted from that file that you sent.

I have confirmed that this is the same behaviour that Google uses for other products where they consume their own API:

- Download or Create Line Items file as CSV or any other supported format.
- Edit Line Items.
- Upload Line Items.

So basically you only need to create a script that edits CSV files and another to authenticate with the API.

Comment: Were you able to create new line items with this method?. Seems it's only possible to make changes to the available line items.

Comment: By "create campaign" did you mean "create lineitem"?. I've added new line items to the csv file and uploaded without getting an error, however the new additions does not reflect in the DBM even after 30 mins. Can you clarify a bit on how to create new line items with the csv file approach?

Comment: @AnuruddhaPremalal, yes. DBM calls them LineItems instead of Campaigns. In order to reflect changes into the DBM account, you need that the external account that tries to access to it has also permissions to perform this operation. Since you are not getting errors, I think you are doing it correctly, the only thing that you might be missing is to set the "dryRun" parameter to False when uploading your LineItems in order to reflect changes in the DBM platform: https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/v1/lineitems/uploadlineitems

Comment: I came across this issue too, but I have not been able to add new line items to an existing insertion order. DBM complains about a missing Line Item ID, but there's no way I can know the ID before the item is created.

Comment: I am still not clear on how are you creating campaign using line items API. Can you please share an example?

Comment: I'm similarly stuck in above struggle: i.e. can't create lineitem as API return error that ID doesn't exist. Anyone know how to create a new lineitem with the API?

Answer (score 0):

DBM API does not allow you to change bid or targeting.
Please see writable field to make your decision.
https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/guides/entity-write/format